# Why or when we will call system function with linux commands instead of writing C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, shell

I'm new to Linux..

I wrote C++ code where I called system function with linux / shell command.
It was much easier to call to system function - less C/C++ code to write and less tests to run or think about all possible cases ... 
My question is why or when we prefer C/C++ code instead of system call with linux/shell function ? I only see advantages - it takes less time for development and more stable (shell commands covered all possible cases).

We use only linux (the code isn't planned to moved to windows or other platforms).

This is my code for example - extract lines from a log that were written later than 'time' (calling 'awk' with system function):

```
#define BUF_LEN 1024

string time = "2019-01-09T23:32:36";//Just for example
string path_to_log = "path to a log";
string output_path = "...";
string cmd_r = "awk '$0 > \"" + time  + "\"' " + path_to_log;
string result;

std::ofstream outfile(output_path);
if(!outfile.is_open())
{        
    printf("Error. Can't open file: [%s]", output_path.c_str());
    return;
}

//Run command to extract lines
char buf[BUF_LEN];
FILE* pipe = popen(cmd_r.c_str(), "r");

if (pipe)
{
    while (fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, pipe) != NULL)
    {
       result.append(buf);
       outfile << buf;
     }
 }
pclose(pipe);
outfile.close();
```

Comment: awk, grep are neither shell functions nor shell commands. They are programs. You can find them in /bin or /usr/bin directories.

Comment: Sure, if you're doing stuff in-house and it saves time / improves reliability, then go for it.  Even better, provide a configuration file detailing such commands so that you can customize the program without recompiling.  However, the fact that you're executing a process like grep or awk using `system` (instead of, say, `fork` + `execv`) does not fill me with confidence that you're particularly serious.  You might need to provide a proper example of what you're doing and why you're concerned.

Comment: Things you should be aware of when executing programs from your own program: (A) the program might not be installed, or may be installed in a non-standard location; (B) the program might be a different variant with argument syntax or output format that differs from the version you tested; (C) running another process creates additional load on the operating system.

Comment: If you have proper library, it would not harder than a function call (plus some `include`), and you will have more control than a executable (which may not build for use in other program).